# Can't remove additional mailbox in Outlook 2016

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I seem to have an additional mailbox in Outlook 2016 which shouldn't exist. I right-click the mailbox and select "Close " but then I get the following error:

[image: This group of folders is associated with an e-mail account. To remove the account, click the File Tab, and on the info tab, click Account Settings. Select the e-mail account, and then click Remove.]

The only e-mail account listed in Account Settings is my primary Exchange mailbox. I checked further into that account's settings, and verified that there are no other mailboxes listed under "Open these additional mailboxes:".

I've already deleted and re-created my Outlook profile, but this problem persists. What else should I do to rectify this issue?

Comment: It would’ve helped tremendously to give us a screen shot of the “other” mailbox. Regardless, whatever it is, it is most definitely associated with your mailbox. You’re either a delegate for another mailbox or have been given access to a shared mailbox or full access to another person’s mailbox. This is all done on the exchange server, or by another user. Outlook adds these automatically to your view.

Comment: @Appleoddity The other mailbox is a shared mailbox. But I don't have the same problem with another shared mailbox I have access to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked on the Exchange side? You could have been given full mailbox access to the mailbox by an Exchange admin, with automapping enabled. This won't be visible from Outlook.

Answer (score -1):

We can view the following attribute in ADSI Edit or ADUC:

Right-click this shared mailbox, in the Attribute Editor, double click the msExchDelegateListLink attribute, check if your account is listed there. You can remove your account from the msExchDelegateListLink attribute to clear Automapping. Restart Outlook and check if the shared mailbox is removed